# docker logs --details flag showing nothing more

Tags: docker, logging

I try to see docker logs with the --details flag

I read the docs but i see no difference with or without the flag : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

For exemple this command echoes the date every second.

```
$ docker run --name test -d busybox sh -c "while true; do $(echo date); sleep 1; done"
e9d836000532
```

This command shows logs :

```
$ docker logs e9d836000532

Sun Jan 26 16:01:55 UTC 2020
...
```

This command adds nothing more that a "space on the left" :

```
$ docker logs --details e9d836000532
...
 Sun Jan 26 16:01:55 UTC 2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docker documentation:

> The docker logs --details command will add on extra attributes, such
>   as environment variables and labels, provided to --log-opt when
>   creating the container.

currently you have an extra space on the left when you use `docker log --details` because you probably do not use `--log-opt` when you create your container.

For your interest, `--log-opt` is used to use an another log driver than docker default's one

Try out this one :
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/

Comment: they say "details" will add labels. Then if i add "--label test=test" when creating the container i should get it when using --details no ? i get nothing more. when i use "--log-opt labels=service" i still see nothing more. can u provide an exemple please ?

Comment: It's depend on your log driver, you can use `fluentd` if you want to use `--label` for extra log. I don't think docker default's one handle that